# Full width tiny chart with Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to have a chart stick to the border of my container with Recharts. I don't use any axis, just the line. I cannot get ride of the margins.

Simple reproduction here: https://jsfiddle.net/jdcpqg5k/2

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  ComposedChart,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Tooltip,
  Area,
  Line,
} from "recharts";

const Chart = ({ data }) => (
      <div style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}>
        <ResponsiveContainer>
          <ComposedChart 
            data={data}
            margin={{ top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
          >
            <Tooltip />
            <Area type="monotone" dataKey="count" />
            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="total" />
          </ComposedChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
  );
```

A dirty workaround is to set margin as follow:

```js
<ComposedChart
    data={data}
    margin={{ top: 0, right: -15, left: -15, bottom: 0 }}
>
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="total" />
</ComposedChart>
```

But it is not responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space around the chart is coming from padding of the container. Set the padding to 0 for `<ResponsiveContainer>`.